# Why can't you find data in an XML when I have proof of its existence?

Tags: oracle, xml-namespaces, xmltype, xmltable

I am calling a web service that returns an xml to me. When trying to obtain the information of said response, using the sentence that is included below, no data is found, that is, the sentence does not return any information. Possibly there is something in my sentence that is not correct, but I cannot locate the problem.

We have the following sentence:

```
SELECT T.MYCODE
FROM XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/',
                            'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP-ENV",
                            'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' AS "SOAP-ENC",
                            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'          AS "xsd",
                            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi",
                            'http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/euExpressRateBook/RateMsgResponse' AS "rateresp"),
    '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/rateresp:RateResponse/Provider'
    PASSING  xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
                            xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                            xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                            <SOAP-ENV:Header
                                xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                                <rateresp:RateResponse xmlns:rateresp="http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/euExpressRateBook/RateMsgResponse">
                                    <Provider code="DHL">
                                        <Notification code="0">
                                            <Message></Message>
                                        </Notification>
                                        <Service type="N">
                                            <TotalNet>
                                                <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                                                <Amount>7.34</Amount>
                                            </TotalNet>
                                            <Charges>
                                                <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                                                <Charge>
                                                    <ChargeType>EXPRESS DOMESTIC</ChargeType>
                                                    <ChargeAmount>6.46</ChargeAmount>
                                                </Charge>
                                                <Charge>
                                                    <ChargeCode>FF</ChargeCode>
                                                    <ChargeType>FUEL SURCHARGE</ChargeType>
                                                    <ChargeAmount>0.88</ChargeAmount>
                                                </Charge>
                                            </Charges>
                                            <DeliveryTime>2020-01-22T23:59:00</DeliveryTime>
                                            <CutoffTime>2020-01-21T16:00:00</CutoffTime>
                                            <NextBusinessDayInd>N</NextBusinessDayInd>
                                        </Service>
                                    </Provider>
                                </rateresp:RateResponse>
                            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>')
    COLUMNS MYCODE VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@code') t;
```

I expected the string "DHL" to return, but it returns nothing.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only error is in defining `'http://tempuri.org/'` as the default namespace. But it does not exist in your XML at all.

You can add the default namespace to your XML or remove the definition of the default namespace in XMLTABLE.